# How to set textarea sit at the bottom and <ul> scroll

Tags: html, css, textarea

I am developing a chat application which has a WhatsApp like UI. There is a `textarea` at the bottom and messages stay top of it.

My current code is as follows :

```css
textarea {
  border: 0 none white;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="padding: 0 5px 0 5px;">
  <ul id="discussion" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
    <li>Placeholder</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="textentry" style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; width:99%;">
    <textarea id="message" style="width: 100%; height: 1em; background-color:lightgray;" rows="1"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

At start everything is normal. Every message appends to `<ul>` as `<li>`.

But when lines exceeds the initial `<ul>` height, I am losing my original style. `textarea` is not positioned at the bottom, instead it is placed above `<ul>` and the `<ul>` scrolls within the page. (Please see the image below)
[image]

What I want is to scroll the messages in their own place without expanding over or under `textarea` and `<ul>` items are scrolled to display the latest message.

How can I accomplish this task?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your css like this:

```
textarea
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;

    border: 0 none white;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. This fixes the textare sit at the bottom but still my <ul> hides some of the latest lined under the textara. How can I make <ul> fiish just before my textarea?

Comment: it has to do with your height , this should fix it <ul id="discussion" style="overflow-y: scroll;height:550px">

Answer (score 0):

To set the ul finish before the text area you can set a height to the ul. So you also can scroll the ul and the page is not enlarging

```
#discussion{
  height:600px;
}
```